# Resolving conflict in git

Tags: git

I notices that quite often, when I have conflicts, I simply want to choose. For example, when applying a stash I ran into this:

```
sfGuardGroup:
  g1:
    label: Project Manager
    name: manager
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
    Permissions: [p_manager]
    Children: [g2, g3, g4, g5]
=======
    Permissions: [p_manager, p2, p3, p4, p5, p_request]
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
  g2:
    label: Junior PM (USA)
    name: junior-manager-usa
    Permissions: [p_junior, p_junior_usa, p_request]
...
```

I know exactly that I want to keep everything that is marked "Updated upstream" and drop \ ignore "Stashed changes". Is it possible to just tell git to "Use upstream version of this file"?

Comment: What does "upstream version" refer to? The version of the file before applying the stash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git checkout HEAD -- path/to/file
```

Comment: What if I want to do the opposite; that is, keep the stashed changes?

Comment: To keep the stashed changes instead: If `git stash pop` results in conflicts it doesn't actually drop the applied stash, so you should be able to do `git checkout stash@{0} -- path/to/file`

Comment: loved your answer